# UIImage+Resize crashes without memory warning

Tags: xcode, ios4, uiimage, image-resizing

Herer is my resize routine...
in the line CGContextDrawImage the app crashes after 2 or 3 calls of the routine.

there is no memory warning or something.
it just chrashes

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
                transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
           drawTransposed:(BOOL)transpose
     interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGRect transposedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newRect.size.height, newRect.size.width);


    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

    // Build a context that's the same dimensions as the new size
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));

    // Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image


////////////AFTER THAT IT CRASHS!!!


     CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef);

        // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
        CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
        UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

        // Clean up
        CGContextRelease(bitmap);
        CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

        return newImage;
    }
```

someone a hint?

regards, phil

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should add `autorelease pool` or `@autorelease{}` for ARC?
I think, it would help.

Comment: tanks, i am working with ARC -> how is the in ARC the @autorelease{} syntax exactly?

Comment: @autorelease{ //some block code} will create a custom autorelease pool for block.